# Autocomplete selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autocomplete

I have the list which has multiple links under each section. Each section has different inks I need to click a particular link under each section. I have written the below code but when it executes it gives me: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"s2id_CountryId\"]/a")).click();
List<WebElement> link2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-drop\"]/ul//li[.]"));

for (int i = 0; i <= link2.size(); i++) {
    if (link2.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("ALGERIA")) {
        link2.get(i).click();
    }
}

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\\\"s2id_GlobalId\\\"]/a")).click();
List<WebElement> link = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-drop\"]/ul//li[.]"));

for (int i = 0; i <= link.size(); i++) {
    if (link.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("BNZ (Global)")) {
        link.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws that error? Also, post the relevant HTML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
 List<WebElement> listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("yourXpath"));
 listOfLinks.forEach(link -> {
     if (link.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("your text")) {
         link.click();
         }
     });
```

forEach will get each link from your list and it will do with each whatever you have between those brackets. In this case, the if condition.

For the second part you can also use foreach. You can also put waits in for each, so for each link it will wait for a certain time.

If you want to use lambdas, you need java 8.

Edit: after the info you got me, I have managed to write this for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".//src//browser//chromedriver.exe");
    yourMethodName("xpathExample", "xPathListPathExample", "iWantToFindThis","theTextIWantToComplete");
}

private static void yourMethodName(String xPathOfTheElement,String xPathListPath, String theTextYouWantToFind, String theTextYouWantToComplete) throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathOfTheElement)).sendKeys(theTextYouWantToComplete);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    List<WebElement> listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPathListPath));
    listOfLinks.forEach(link -> {
        if (link.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(theTextYouWantToFind)) {
            link.click();
        }
    });
}
```

Hopefully this is clear enough for you.

Comment: Thanks for ur response... I need to know one more thing... how can I call it on run time.. while in case I have to handle two more autocomplete fields on the same page

Comment: Here I have been attached by code .. plz overview that,.. and give me suggestion  to made changes..